# Strange write()/File behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a long python application, and within it's workflow I am trying to write snippets of strings to an error log.

I was using:

```
lines = ['ERROR TITLE: user ' + str(user_id) + ' ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' dataframe is empty for this user']
with open(ERROR_LOG_PATH + ERROR_LOG_NAME, 'a') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(lines))
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()
```

This worked and the result was a single line of text in a text document expressing a specific error I wanted to record.

The issue came when I realised I was duplicating the with open call throughout my code. So I attempted to convert the write open call to a custom function like this:

```
def write_to_log(lines):

    with open(ERROR_LOG_PATH + ERROR_LOG_NAME, 'a') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(lines))
        file.write('\n')
        file.close()
```

Then I call the write to log function each time I need to pass it the list to write like this:

```
write_to_log([ERROR TITLE: user ' + str(user_id) + ' ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' dataframe is empty for this user])
```

Now however, I get weird output within the text file. instead of readable text I get:

[image]

I then commented out the change and reverted back to a write file call per error text call. but I seem to be getting the error no matter what now.

Scope:

I am writing and executing the code via VSCode on a mac. the text file is going to a file location on a network NAS, and I have tried to open the file on various machines and with various text editors (as I thought it may be a NotePad issue on my windows machine), but the bad characters remain.

I am clearly doing something stupid. all assistance greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Duncan

Comment: FWIW: you don't need to call `file.close()` if you're opening the file in a context manager using `with` - the whole idea of the context manager is that the file (or whatever resource) is closed/disposed of/whatever when the context manager block is exited. Also, `file` is shadowing a reserved keyword of the same name - this isn't likely to be an issue, but it's something to watch out for as a best-practice thing!

Comment: The only debugging you've done is open the file in Notepad? It's very likely Notepad just completely mis-guesses the file's encoding. Try opening it with some other text or hex editor.

Comment: You have missed the `'` at the beginning. Don't know if it was an editing mistake or a code mistake. Wanted to point that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Youre calling file.close() while using context manager, but you dont need to because file will be closed automatically
2. Try to specify the encoding

```
def write_to_log(lines):
    with open(ERROR_LOG_PATH + ERROR_LOG_NAME, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(lines) + '\n')
```

Comment: Legand! implemented both points, the function now works as intended, @capy your are a star.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working if this is how you intended

```
def write_to_log(lines):

    with open(ERROR_LOG_PATH + ERROR_LOG_NAME, 'a') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(lines))
        file.write('\n')
        file.close()

user_id = 1
firstName ='hello'
lastName = 'goodbye'

ERROR_LOG_PATH = 'rest'
ERROR_LOG_NAME ='test'
lines = ['ERROR TITLE: user ' + str(user_id) + ' ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' dataframe is empty for this user']

write_to_log(lines) //passed lines here
```

OUTPUT

```
ERROR TITLE: user 1 hello goodbye dataframe is empty for this user
```